# What is the most used class in Google collections framework?

Tags: java, entity-framework, collections, frameworks

I wonder what is the most useful class in the [Google collections framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)?

Comment: How do you intend to get an answer? Or is this a poll?

Comment: The class that provides the functionality you happen to be looking for :-)

Comment: U guys sucks, he just wanted to know what classes are usefull in that lib.

Comment: you guys don't suck, no way...  I just had to be more clear.  I just wonder which one from that collection do you use the most. Jon Skeet rocks by answering this question.  But I'd love to evaluate your responses too, fellow programmers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience, `Iterables` and `Lists`.

I use `Lists.newArrayList` frequently (usually as a static import) and `Iterables` is the closest that Java gets to LINQ...

Oh, and not particularly collection-y, but `Preconditions.checkNotNull` is very handy too, again with a static import:

```
public MyClass (String name, ...)
{
    this.name = checkNotNull(name);
    // etc
}
```

Then there's all the immutability stuff, multi-maps, `MapMaker` etc... It's just a great library. KevinB et al rock :)

Answer (score 8):

Inside Google, the answer is com.google.common.collect.Lists.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Multimap a lot.

I cursed then a little bit when new ArrayListMultimap() was not working, but then after googling a lot I figured out that they were using ArrayListMultimap.create(), which is cleaner as you don't need to specify the map types twice (as recommended in the Effective Java book, which the author as far as I know is the chief Java dude at google).

Nice thing about Multimap is that, among the several implementations of it, there was one where the list behaves as a set (no duplicated elements, actually, it's no duplicated key + value elements), that really helped.

I think it's a great library and I am moving into using more and more often instead of the commons collection.

Comment: Shame ImmutableSetMultimap does not behave as a set (it throws an exception if you add the same key/value pair twice.)

Comment: finn: you must be referring to ImmutableSetMultimap.Builder. That was a mistake. A helpful user reported it (before your post), so I fixed it, as of 1.0-rc3.